# Cite in the caption of a graphic but not in \listoffigures?

Tags: floats, table-of-contents, captions, citing

Sometimes I'd like to cite the reference in the caption of a graphic. But I want to avoid that this citation is displayed in the `\listoffigures`. How can I achieve that?

Fore example with this code:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics{overview_pyramid.png}
\caption{Overview pyramid \cite{LM2010}}\label{fg:overview_pyramid}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not simply use

```
\caption[Overview pyramid]{Overview pyramid \cite{LM2010}}\label{fg:overview_pyramid}
```

Comment: Are you working on software-metrics?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but more or less yes.