# Quotation marks in section titles

Tags: hyperref, pdf, sectioning, punctuation, bookmarks

I have a question similar to that in [Cite in the caption of a graphic but not in \listoffigures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/cite-in-the-caption-of-a-graphic-but-not-in-listoffigures)

I'm using this to create bookmarks in my generated PDFs:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
```

My problem, is that I'm using inverted commas (quotation marks) in my section/subsection titles.  However, my PDF bookmarks come out with backticks and two apostrophes (``` text... ''`), instead of a proper pair of inverted commas.  Is there a way around this?

In the question I linked to above, I see that I can specify an optional title for places like this, and if worse comes to worse, I could leave out the quotation marks.  I'd really prefer to keep them, though.

Comment: How do you create the inverted commas? Are you using a macro, an unicode character or else?

Comment: Your title asks about the `\cite` command, but your question is about quotation marks. Is your title wrong or your question?

Comment: I changed the title, to what I believe is what you ask. Please change it again if it is incorrect.

Comment: Nope--that's what it should have been.  Sorry!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If, instead of the ligatures (which, I believe, is how the "double backping and double apostrophe become proper qoutation marks"-mechanism works), you use unicode characters, it seems to work as expected. Alternatively, you can use `\texorpdfstring{for TeX typesetting}{for bookmarks}` in your `\section` command.

This illustrates the two options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[bookmarks,pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{The phrases ``nudge nudge'' and “wink wink”  }

\section{The \texorpdfstring{``larch''}{"larch"}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using Uniode characters didn't work for me, actually.  It works in the TeX output, but not in the PDF file, for some reason.  The `\texorpdfstring` command does the trick, though.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's viewer dependent. I'm using Adobe Reader 9 on Ubuntu. When you say it doesn't work in the pdf file, do you mean only the bookmarks sidebar, or something else? Also, one should probably be careful with copying unicode characters from a browser to an editor; all sorts of things can go wrong in that process. The two I used above are 0x201C and 0x201D (LEFT/RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK). If you do want a pair of quotation marks where one can distinguish the left from the right, you could also try »guillemets«. They are even in the latin1 range.

Comment: Sorry--I meant it doesn't work in the sidebar.  Within the document, it prints just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This gives different quotation marks in TeX and the bookmarks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{My ``foo''}{My "foo"}}
bar

\end{document}
```