# suspended hyphen without linebreak between word and hyphen

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, babel

I have a word combination like this *metallo-porphyrins and -phthalocyanines* which eventually gives a linebreak between the hyphen and the word phthalocyanines. I tried to include the `ngerman` package as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngerman-s-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-lan). This works fine but messes up the quotes used in the text elsewhere (I used so far `"word"`). I know I could use ''word`` instead for having english quotes. However the suspended hyphen appears once in the text and the quotes several times in the document (several files). I would therefore prefere to use a different solution for the hyphen. If this is not possible and I have to change the quotes, then I still get the ugly bookmarks and would need an alternative to this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/quotation-marks-in-section-titles).

Comment: `\mbox{-}` should remove the breakpoint

Comment: This works. I see I should probably anyway change the quotes to ``word'' as the output with "word" is not looking nice (I have apparently overseen this before)

Comment: Setting `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` removes (globally) beak-points at such explicit hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

`\mbox{-}` should remove the breakpoint.