# Overleaf natbib \cite{website} error

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf

I've recently moved my work from texmaker to Overleaf. I linked my Mendeley library to Overleaf.

Now, when I try to compile the document everything works just fine, except for website citations. Any thought on how this can be fixed? Since it's a Mendeley import I can't manually change them. See working example below (note that I input chapters into the main.tex file using \input thus there is no preamble) and I use a .sty file that loads packages, which contains natbib:

```
Some text ... see figure \ref{fig:ecommerceGrowth}.

\begin{figure}[htb]
...
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/ecommerceGrowth}
  \caption{Worldwide e-commerce growth 2015-2020. Adapted from \cite{EMarketer2016}}\label{fig:ecommerceGrowth}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

And a copy of the .bib entry:

```
@misc{EMarketer2016,
    title = {{Worldwide Retail Ecommerce Sales Will Reach {\$}1.915 Trillion This Year - eMarketer}},
    year = {2016},
    author = {{eMarketer}},
    url = {https://www.emarketer.com/Article/Worldwide-Retail-Ecommerce-Sales-Will-Reach-1915-Trillion-This-Year/1014369}
}
```

And ofcourse the Overleaf error (identical for all 3 inputs):

```
/main.tex:
Package natbib warning: There are undefined citations.
/main.lof:8:
Package natbib warning: citation 'EMarketer2016' on page \textlatin {v} undefined on input line 8.
```

In have the idea it's triggered by the @misc since all other entries are working (bib file is 200 entries), of which 3 @misc which are not working. Is this an overleaf issue or am I missing some package?

And btw: when I type \cite{} the entrance does pop up in the dropdown list.
Recompiling or the recompile from scratch option doesn't solve the problem, Neither does deleting the entry and re-adding it.

Worked fine before for another project I have on Overleaf which has Mendeley library and website inputs as @misc.

Edit: when I export it and compile it using texmaker it runs without any problems...

Edit2: The MWE you requested does work. As such I guess it must be somewhere within the underlying Overleaf system - everything is copy pasted into the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{libtest.bib}
@misc{EMarketer2016,
    title = {{Worldwide Retail Ecommerce Sales Will Reach {\$}1.915 Trillion This Year - eMarketer}},
    year = {2016},
    author = {{eMarketer}},
    url = {https://www.emarketer.com/Article/Worldwide-Retail-Ecommerce-Sales-Will-Reach-1915-Trillion-This-Year/1014369}
}

@misc{Corcoran2002,
author = {Corcoran, Jem N},
booktitle = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
isbn = {3540609318},
issn = {0162-1459},
pages = {360--360},
pmid = {36621914},
title = {{Modelling Extremal Events for Insurance and Finance}},
volume = {97},
year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 

\section*{A section}
This does not work in actual code \cite{EMarketer2016}. \newline
This does work in actual code \cite{Corcoran2002}. \newline

\bibliography{libtest}
\end{document}
```

Edit 3: I've been narrowing down the problem and now know that:
1) citations work just fine outside the figure environment;
2) when I include \cite{sourceA} in the \caption{} it crashes.

This works:

```
\cite{EMarketer2016}

 \begin{figure}[htb]
    ...
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/ecommerceGrowth}
      \caption{Worldwide e-commerce growth 2015-2020. Adapted from XX }\label{fig:ecommerceGrowth}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

And this doesn't:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/ecommerceGrowth}
  \caption{Worldwide e-commerce growth 2015-2020. Adapted from \cite{EMarketer2016}}\label{fig:ecommerceGrowth}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Again, this same code works in any other project I have on Overleaf (or texmaker), thus knowing for sure the code is OK.

Found it!
The problem occured when I tried to compile a `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, which apparently crashes when using `\cite` within the curly brackets of `\caption{}`. Solution was easy (credits go to [this stackexchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/cite-in-the-caption-of-a-graphic-but-not-in-listoffigures)). Simply use the options brackets of `\caption` as such:

Wrong: `\caption{Worldwide e-commerce growth 2015-2020. Adapted from \cite{EMarketer2016}}`

Correct: `\caption[Worldwide e-commerce growth 2015-2020.]{Worldwide e-commerce growth 2015-2020. Adapted from \cite{EMarketer2016}}`

Thanks for all your help guys, much appreciated. Hope this helps others who encounter the same problem ;)

Comment: Sorry, typo while copying the error message (overleaf doesn't let you copy paste it...)

Comment: Check the log-file and check the .blg-file for errors/messages.

Comment: Did you specify the correct .bib file in `\bibliography{...}` and have a valid `\bibliographystyle{...}`? https://www.overleaf.com/help/238

Comment: `\cite` is a "fragile" command (in LaTeX jargon), which causes issues if it's encountered inside a "moving argument" (more LaTeX jargon, sorry) such as `\caption{...}`. Change the instruction to `\caption{... Adapted from \protect{\cite{EMarketer2016}}}` to fix the issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't think I can acces a .blg- file since Overleaf doesn't export it. What should I look for in the log file? (sorry i'm kinds new to latex...)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Yes normal as always: \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{library}. Since it's mendeley import you only have 1 .bib file which contains all your mendeley citations

Comment: @Mico I've tried but doesn't seem to fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Go to the project button, then choose "download as zip-file" and in the dropdown menu "input and output files". Then you should get everything and can inspect the files. Btw: I don't use overleaf. But it took me only 5 minutes to find this out by looking at the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know how to export, Overleaf just doesn't add this file to it unfortunately. All files available: aux, fdb_latexmk, fls, lof, log, lot, out, pdf, synctex.gz, tex, toc. I've been looking in the log file but can't find any clues there

Comment: I tested it. The blg-file *is* in the zip. Check if the extension is hidden (windows e.g. often says that it is another file type).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sorry, it's really not. It's also not hidden since I can see such files when I'm using texmaker to compile. Maybe this is a clue to the problem. I'll also contact Overleaf as it seems to be more than just a small typo..

Comment: Can you make the zip-file available?

Comment: Your MWE works fine with overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dkjyryzhkdpb Does your MWE work for on overleaf?

Comment: If the `.blg` isn't in the `Input and Output Files` .zip (and no `.bbl` as well) it may mean bibtex wasn't triggered. If nothing still works you may want to send your project's read-and-edit URL to support@overleaf.com (if you don't want to share it publicly), where someone can have a look. (Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)

Comment: @LianTzeLim I indeed can't share the files publicly due to confidentiality issues... I'll contact Overleaf help desk then. Strange case is that I've 2 different projects, of which this one i'm working in has many copy pastes from the other project. The other project has the same citations and does compile as supposed to. |That's why i'm pretty sure it's not in my code. 

I have a new error now which concerns .bbl as such it might be triggered: /main.bbl:12: use of \hyper@link@ doesn't match its definition. \text@command #1->\def \reserved@a { #1}\ifx\reserved@a\@empty\let\check@ ... l.12

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved according to edit